# Lightbox 2 redirects me to the image file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, lightbox, lightbox2

I have a problem with lightbox. After clicking the image file it just redirects me to the image.
This is the code in the cshtml.

```
<a href="" data-lightbox="screenshot" >
<img src="" />
</a>
```

The href and src's values are automatically being inserted by a jquery code and is guaranteed to be the same image. The styles and scripts that are necessary are also inserted.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" ></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/lightbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Styles/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

How do I view the image using lightbox instead of it redirecting? I followed the instructions in this link but it still did not work: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: It seems that you forgot to ask a question. Please take a [tour] as well.

Answer (score 2):

Put the

```
<script src="../../Scripts/lightbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

line at the end, before the closing /body